# Operación aritmética dentro de un input

Tags: javascript, html

Este es el problema, pero más bien una duda... quise hacer del input del buscador de mi página una calculadora lo resolví con el siguiente código:

```
document.querySelector('#s-s').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let input = document.querySelector('#s-s').value;
  let result = Function("return " + input)();
  document.getElementById('s-s').value = (result);
});
```

Aprendí que es incorrecto usar eval() así que lei encontré que es igual hacerlo con una Function... todo bien si escribo en el input 2+2 suma 4 pero el PROBLEMA es cuando borró, automáticamente me sale UNDEFINED, como lo solucionó, muchas gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0):

para empezar yo utilizaría el evento "change" en lugar del "input", así puedes poner la operación que quieras y hasta que no pulses intro no se ejecuta.
Por otro lado, cuando el campo está vacío, es normal que te devuelva undefined, pues estás haciendo una operación matemática sobre "" (nada) por eso te devuelve undefined. Simplemente, haz una comprobación antes de mostrar el resultado y si es undefined, le pones el valor que quieras que muestre, en el ejemplo que te pongo a continuación es el campo vacío.

```js
document.querySelector('#s-s').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let input = document.querySelector('#s-s').value;
  let result = Function("return " + input)();
  if (result === undefined){result = "";}
  document.getElementById('s-s').value = (result);
});
```

```html
<input id="s-s">
```

Comment: Era tan sencillo, muchas gracias por la solución, también por el tip de usar "change" gracias